# Why do I need buffer in WebSocket.ReceiveAsync() when the function itself returns the result?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core

In `webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token)` method, why do I need to pass buffer bytes array as a parameter (to save the incoming data in) when the function returns the received data?

```
var incoming = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrong, in `incoming` you get an [`WebSocketReceiveResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocketreceiveresult(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains info about the number of bytes received and so on but no buffer with the data itself.

Data are stored in your `buffer` array

Comment: Ok that makes sense now, I was reading about WebSockets before starting programming them. Therefore I didn't try to get the data from incoming. Thank you!

Comment: no  this is not the right explanation  from MSDN  'The Result property on the task object returns a Byte array containing the received data. '

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin : if so you can accept the answer.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel : Do you have a link ? Receive gets an Array of Bytes, ReceiveAsync don't

Comment: yes this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've read it, but the signature is clear, it returns a WebSocketReceiveResult and in it, there is no buffer. Try it out by coding, you will see it by yourself.

Comment: I 'm trying to give a full  answer with  a full  explanation

Comment: Here `buffer` is of Type `ArraySegment<byte>`, while in your `WebSocketReceiveResult` there is no Array, List, Enumerable containing your data.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I am going to accept Arnaud´s Answer till you provide better answer then I can accept yours.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel - I suspect it's a copy & paste error in the documentation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  yes I confirm  me too I suspect  a documentation error because does not make a sense